# Error building the config :no server set to register to the hub

Tags: selenium

I have a maven project which includes selenium and selion. I get this message after upgrading from selenium 2.47.1 to 2.52.0 (I use selion 1.0.0):

```
02.25.2016 11:31:52.377,[12] com.paypal.selion INFO LocalHub spawned
02.25.2016 11:31:52.459,[12] com.paypal.selion.grid.InstallHelper INFO Verifying SeLion Grid installation...
02.25.2016 11:31:52.468,[27] com.paypal.selion.grid.AbstractBaseLauncher INFO This instance is considered a SeLion Grid Node
02.25.2016 11:31:52.472,[27] com.paypal.selion.grid.SeLionGridLauncher INFO Launching a selenium grid node
Error building the config :no server set to register to the hub
Usage: java -jar selenium-server.jar -role hub [options]

  -host:
    <IP | hostname> : usually not needed and determined
      automatically. For exotic network configuration, network with
      VPN, specifying the host might be necessary.

  -port:
    <xxxx> : the port the remote/hub will listen on. Default to 4444.

  -throwOnCapabilityNotPresent:
    <true | false> default to true. If true, the hub will reject test
      requests right away if no proxy is currently registered that can
      host that capability.Set it to false to have the request queued
      until a node supporting the capability is added to the grid.

  -newSessionWaitTimeout:
    <XXXX>. Default to no timeout ( -1 ) the time in ms after which a
      new test waiting for a node to become available will time
      out.When that happens, the test will throw an exception before
      starting a browser.

  -capabilityMatcher:
    a class implementing the CapabilityMatcher interface. Defaults to
      org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher. Specify
      the logic the hub will follow to define if a request can be
      assigned to a node.Change this class if you want to have the
      matching process use regular expression instead of exact match
      for the version of the browser for instance. All the nodes of a
      grid instance will use the same matcher, defined by the registry.

  -prioritizer:
    a class implementing the Prioritizer interface. Default to null (
      no priority = FIFO ).Specify a custom prioritizer if you need the
      grid to process the tests from the CI, or the IE tests first for
      instance.

  -servlets:
    <com.mycompany.MyServlet,com.mycompany.MyServlet2> to register a
      new servlet on the hub/node. The servlet will accessible under
      the path  /grid/admin/MyServlet /grid/admin/MyServlet2

  -grid1Yml:
    a YML file following grid1 format.

  -hubConfig:
    a JSON file following grid2 format that defines the hub
      properties.

  -browserTimeout:
    The timeout in seconds a browser can hang

This synopsis lists options available in hub role only. To get help
  on the command line options available for other roles run the server
  with -help name and the corresponding -role name value.
```

It should be ran on a Jenkins slave. Actually, it is ran by maven, so I don't know how to change parameters when SeLion tries to create a selenium grid node.
How am I supposed to get it running?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to an incompatible change in selenium from the two versions you mentioned. The fix was committed here - https://github.com/paypal/SeLion/commit/02cffa14080307e5f3aaa7cdaa342f3f2fec3509 which is part of SeLion 1.1.0 (currently in development, So available as a SNAPSHOT)